# What is redistlist files in redist directory?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

In RAD Studio installation directory (e.g.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0`), there is a `Redist` contains some `*.redistlist` files:

```
c:\> dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\redist\*.redistlist"

 Volume in drive S is RAD Studio 10.4.2
 Volume Serial Number is 026F-0E48

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Redist

20/02/2021  07:55 AM                67 iossimulator.redistlist
20/02/2021  07:55 AM             1,384 linux64.redistlist
20/02/2021  07:55 AM             2,273 osx32.redistlist
20/02/2021  07:55 AM             2,100 osx64.redistlist
20/02/2021  07:55 AM             3,363 win32.redistlist
20/02/2021  07:55 AM             2,939 win64.redistlist
               6 File(s)         12,126 bytes
```

The content of the `redistlist` file is a list of runtime packages filename.  What is the purpose of the `redistlist` file?  Can it be utilized for deployment task?  Or it simply record available runtime packages only?

Comment: "make.proj" in the same directory comments: " _These text files contain a list of files to copy from the bin directory into the redist\platform directories._ ". "redistsetup.bat" in the same directory explains it is used to " _invoke msbuild to process redist files_ " and also refers to "redist.targets" for more detail, still in the same directory.